# CMD console shut down automatically when parsing different files through a FOR - DO structure

Tags: file, for-loop, batch-file

I am basic user of the Windows command prompt and I am getting automatically shut down of this console when parsing the variable defa to the called function. I used %defa% and !defa! not working, although echo shows that the for structure is changing the variable in the right direction. I leave below my code in case that somebody can help me to correct it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd C:\Users\LAPTOPJOSE\Desktop\IMAGEMAGICK\images
set/a "th=870"
for /f "delims=" %%m in ('dir /b /o:n') do if not defined defa set "defa=%%m"
REM Loop calling Callme and updating "defa"
FOR %%h in (*.png) DO (
    echo Defa parsed !defa!
    call:Callme %defa% "%%h" %th%
    set "defa=%%h"
    echo DefaUpdated !defa!
)

:Callme
echo Parameters %1 %2 %3
pause
magick compare -metric RMSE %1 %2 NULL: 2>C:\Users\LAPTOPJOSE\Desktop\IMAGEMAGICK\outputresult.txt
for /F "tokens=2* delims= " %%C in (C:\Users\LAPTOPJOSE\Desktop\IMAGEMAGICK\outputresult.txt) do set "var2=%%~C"
echo Var2 %var2%
set /A res=%var2:~4,3%
echo Result %res%

::Line that causes the console shut down without completing the action
IF %res% GTR %3 (copy %2 C:\Users\LAPTOPJOSE\Desktop\IMAGEMAGICK\diff-images) 
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: Don't you want `call Callme !defa! "%%h" %th%`? (You wrote `callme` is *another* batch file in a comment to your last question; `call :callme` tries to find a label `:callme` within the *current* batchfile)

Comment: Yes, but then I refined my code and passed the function to the same batch file. The problem appears in any case, but now I discovered that  the console shut down just when the last line of Callme (IF....) is run, without the expected result. Have you any idea about where the problem is? Thank you for your support

Comment: "console shuts down": a command line window doesn't just "shut down". If you start your script by double-click, it closes once it's finished or a severe syntax error occurs. Run it manually from an already open `cmd` window and it will not "crash", enabling you to see the errormessage. It it isn't obvious to you, share it with us.

Comment: Btw: you should insert a `goto :eof` a line before the label `:callme` to not run inadvertently into the subroutine (without any parameters)

Comment: Thank you very much, I had time to debug it and I found the first value passed to variable "res" as text, not a number to be compared. I easily resolved it with an If statement and a counter. However, I should introduce a more generic if statement for any iteration (value of my counter) where "res" receives nothing or any thing different from a number. But the initial issue is already resolved and can be clossed.